# How to make image for each x numbers

Tags: php, html

How to replace 200 numbers with an image?

This example :

[image: here]

For example

- When user have 200 numbers He takes 1 image
- When user have 830 He take 4 image

what php code I need it?

Sorry but I havn't Any code

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just divide by 200 and floor it. `$images = floor($number/200);` - live example: https://eval.in/685766

Comment: thanks but, can you replace the numbers with the image in the top

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: sorry @JoeC ...

Comment: @Qirel can you replace numbers with img

Comment: @MaKeL Create a loop to display them `for ($i = 0; $i < floor($number/200); $i++) { /* Show image here, use HTML <img src.... */ }`

Comment: @MaKeL No need to apologise.  I'm just trying to help you by offering you advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$votes = 10334;
$starCount = intval($votes/ 200);
$starCount = $starCount > 5 ? 5 : $starCount; //if maximum 5 stars

$a = 1;
$starsString = '';
for ($a; $a <= $starCount; $a++) {
    $starsString .= '⛤'; // or '<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhAy4.gif" alt="here">'
}

echo $starsString;
```

Comment: Thanks, IS THIS WORK from databaes $votes =$datauser["points"];

Comment: if the data type of $datauser["points"] is an integer, yes :) Try var_dump($datauser["points"]) and see what type of data you get. If this is for points better you rename $votes to $points in 1st and 2nd lines.

Comment: Thanks but this work only for one user

Comment: Sorry for late response, what is the data type of $datauser["points"] in other users. better you can show the response of it. If it's NULL or 0 or false, we will not see any star image

Comment: datatype is numbers

Comment: what are the values this logic not works